# List numbering doesn't restart

Tags: python, python-docx

If you see example here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-lists-python-docx-module/

Code is this:

```
# Import docx NOT python-docx
import docx

# Create an instance of a word document
doc = docx.Document()

# Add a Title to the document
doc.add_heading('GeeksForGeeks', 0)

# Adding list of style name 'List Number'
doc.add_heading('Style: List Number', 3)
# Adding points to the list named 'List Number'
doc.add_paragraph('The first item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number')

doc.add_paragraph('The second item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number')

doc.add_paragraph('The third item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number')

# Adding list of style name 'List Number 2'
doc.add_heading('Style: List Number 2', 3)
# Adding points to the list named 'List Number 2'
doc.add_paragraph('The first item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 2')

doc.add_paragraph('The second item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 2')

doc.add_paragraph('The third item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 2')

# Adding list of style name 'List Number 3'
doc.add_heading('Style: List Number 3', 3)
# Adding points to the list named 'List Number 3'
doc.add_paragraph('The first item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 3')

doc.add_paragraph('The second item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 3')

doc.add_paragraph('The third item in an ordered list.',
                style='List Number 3')

# Now save the document to a location
doc.save('gfg.docx')
```

If for instance I change it List number 2 to just List number, number goes sequentially rather than starting  over like this:
[image: output]

How do I change it such that it is number for list 2 starts over from 1 - 3

Comment: Could you find the solution? If so, do share that would help out others.

Comment: @template have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This solution here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574265/8754028

To summarize:

- uninstall python-docx
- install this fork with support to low level numbering: https://github.com/jlovegren0/python-docx, for more information about this fork, read https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/582
- run the given code, just change `m.val = 'multiLevel'` to `m.val = 'multilevel'`